# Writing to a USB extremely HDD slow, but not with 'sponge'

Tags: linux

This takes 2 mins 9 secs, and I don't know why:

```
time openssl rand 10000000 > foo
```

This takes 0.8 seconds:

```
time openssl rand 10000000 | sponge > foo
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04.1, HP Stream Mini 010, 4TB USB 3.0 Seagate 'Backup Plus' hard drive.

Why is it 161x faster with sponge?

**More Testing...**

1. The same hard drive reformatted to HFS+ on a Mac, and the same two tests yields 1.09 secs and 0.9 secs respectively.
2. Faster work Mac & Parallels & Ubuntu 14.04: 0.4 and 0.2 seconds respectively.

Comment: Which shell are you running this on?

Comment: Just plain old bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Usbmount defaults to a 'sync' mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=usbmount+sync+slow) which makes some categories of write slow

Editing the `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` file and taking out the `sync` property makes it as fast as you'd expect. Specifically the sponge and non-sponge tests having the same time.

Answer (score 0):

sponge has its own buffer and do writing in one step.
man sponge:

```
DESCRIPTION
       sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
       Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing
       the output file.
```

Comment: Thanks, and I knew that already, but it doesn't help me determine root cause of the slowness of writing to the FS.

Comment: But this is the root cause. Try `dd bs=1k` then try `dd bs=1M` to the same device. Buffer does really matter.

Comment: I updated my Q - I've added OS X stats for the same two tests. Buffer/sponge didn't matter in that case.